# Outlook Redemption: Releasing RDOMail from GetMessageFromMsgFile in VBScript

Tags: outlook, vbscript, outlook-redemption

we use VBScript for changing EXIF data of .msg files.

We access msg files using

```
Set Element = Session.GetMessageFromMsgFile(msgFilePath)
```

It works fine, exept that the msg file gets locked, so that writing EXIF data to the file fails.

How can I release the msg file (Element), as Marshal.ReleaseComObject() doesn't work within VBScript? Setting Element=Nothing doesn't work either.

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 0):

In VB script, just setting the `RDOMail` object to `Nothing` will do the job:

```
set Element = Nothing
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry, there was another reference on the Element object. Now it works. Sorry - my fault :). Thanks and best regards! Chris